# Change OpenCL function to C++

Tags: c++, opencl

I am trying to write a code in C++, but after some search on the internet, I found one OpenCL based code is doing exactly the same thing as I want to do in C++. But since this is the first time I see a OpenCL code, I don't know how to change the following functions into c++:

```
const __global float4 *in_buf;

int x = get_global_id(0);
int y = get_global_id(1);

float result = y * get_global_size(0);
```

Is '`const __global float4 *in_buf`' equivalent to '`const float *in_buf`' in c++? And how to change the above other functions? Could anyone help? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, you should take a look at [the OpenCL specification](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/sdk/1.2/docs/man/xhtml/) (I'm assuming it's written in OpenCL 1.x) to better understand functions, types and how a kernel works.

Specifically for your question:

`get_global_id` returns the id of the current work item, and `get_global_size` returns the total number of work items. Since an OpenCL work-item is roughly equivalent to a single iteration in a sequential language, the equivalent of OpenCL's:

```
int x = get_global_id(0);
int y = get_global_id(1);
// do something with x and y
float result = y * get_global_size(0);
```

Will be C's:

```
for (int x = 0; x < dim0; x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < dim1; y++) {
        // do something with x and y
        float result = y * dim0;
    }
}
```

As for `float4` it's a vector type of 4 floats, roughly equivalent to C's `float[4]` (except that it supports many additional operators, such as vector arithmetic). Of course in this case it's a buffer, so an appropriate type would be `float**` or `float[4]*` - or better yet, just pack them together into a `float*` buffer and then load 4 at a time.

Feel free to ignore the `__global` modifier.

Comment: +1; but I'd say a `float4` is more closely equivalent to `std::array<float, 4>`- it can be assigned and copied.

Comment: Maybe it is equivalent to __m128 intrinsic variable?

Answer (score 2):

`const __global float4 *in_buf` is not equivalent to `const float *in_buf`.
The OpenCL uses vector variables, e.g. `floatN`, where N is e.g. 2,4,8. So `float4` is in fact `struct { float w, float x, float y, float z}` with lot of tricks available to express vector operations.

get_global_id(0) gives you the iterator variable, so essentially replace every `get_global_id(dim)` with `for(int x = 0; x< max[dim]; x++)`